# How to update mat-tree to handle add children nodes to leaf nodes (convert leaf nodes to parents)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-5, angular-cdk

I'm using [Angular Material6 Tree component](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview) with check boxes.

In the [Original Example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aaaxbedprnre?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts), We only can add new child to parent Node. 
What If I want to add a new child to a [leaf node](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ax72ew?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by adding few lines to insertItem and addNewItem functions. [stackblitz fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ax72ew?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts)

```
     addNewItem(node: TodoItemFlatNode) {
        const parentNode = this.flatNodeMap.get(node);
        /*** this block will be used to determine wither we should expand the subtree or not.      **/ 
        let isParentHasChildren: boolean = false;
        if (parentNode.children)
          isParentHasChildren = true;
        /** end of the block **/
        this.database.insertItem(parentNode!, '');
        // expand the subtree only if the parent has children (parent is not a leaf node)
        if (isParentHasChildren)
          this.treeControl.expand(node);
      }

      insertItem(parent: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
        const child = <TodoItemNode>{ item: name };
        if (parent.children) { // parent already has children
          parent.children.push(child);
          this.dataChange.next(this.data);
        }
        else { // if parent is a leaf node
          parent.children = [];
          parent.children.push(child);
          this.dataChange.next(this.data);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Do you know how to make the new child node expandable if you immediately add a child node to that child node just created?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52578743/how-to-make-mat-tree-component-angular-material-6-0-1 .help me out

Comment: When adding new items to the leaf nodes, it collapses the new nodes. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 6):

although it is an old question I will answer for those who will ask again how to do.

First, add the + button to the leaf node :

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="addNewItem(node)"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon></button>
```

Then, use a little trick to refresh tree.

```
refreshTree() {
    let _data = this.dataSource.data;
    this.dataSource.data = [];
    this.dataSource.data = _data;
  }
```

I added a call to refreshTree function inside the data change subscription :

```
_database.dataChange.subscribe(data => {
        this.dataSource.data = data;
        this.refreshTree();
      });
```