# How to make mat-tree component Angular Material 6.0.1

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am trying to do a material angular mat-tree based app but when i run this code it is not displaying values and i am not getting any error how can i resolve this help me out to move forward

when we open app we need to show class names

below i have added my html and component code

```
<mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNestedChild">
    <li>
      <div class="mat-tree-node">
        <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
                [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename">
          <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
            {{nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
          </mat-icon>
        </button>

      </div>
      <ul [class.example-tree-invisible]="!nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node)">
        <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </mat-nested-tree-node>
```

component:

```
const TREE_DATA = [
{
    "class":"ece",
    "count":60,
    "students": [

            {"name":"a","id":"11"},
            {"name":"b","id":"12"},
            {"name":"c","id":"13"},
            {"name":"d","id":"14"}

    ]
},
{
    "class":"mech",
    "count":60,
    "students": [

            {"name":"r","id":"21"},
            {"name":"e","id":"22"},
            {"name":"w","id":"23"},
            {"name":"q","id":"24"}

    ]
}
];


@Injectable()
export class FileDatabase {
  dataChange = new BehaviorSubject<FileNode[]>([]);

  get data(): FileNode[] { return this.dataChange.value; }

  constructor() {
    this.initialize();
  }

  initialize() {

    const dataObject = TREE_DATA;


    const data = this.buildFileTree(dataObject, 0);


    this.dataChange.next(data);
  }


  buildFileTree(obj: object, level: number): FileNode[] {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce<FileNode[]>((accumulator, key) => {
      const value = obj[key];
      const node = new FileNode();
      node.filename = key;

      if (value != null) {
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
          node.children = this.buildFileTree(value, level + 1);
        } else {
          node.type = value;
        }
      }

      return accumulator.concat(node);
    }, []);
  }
}

/**
 * @title Tree with nested nodes
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'tree-nested-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'tree-nested-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['tree-nested-overview-example.css'],
  providers: [FileDatabase]
})
export class TreeNestedOverviewExample {
  nestedTreeControl: NestedTreeControl<FileNode>;
  nestedDataSource: MatTreeNestedDataSource<FileNode>;

  constructor(database: FileDatabase) {
    this.nestedTreeControl = new NestedTreeControl<FileNode>(this._getChildren);
    this.nestedDataSource = new MatTreeNestedDataSource();

    database.dataChange.subscribe(data => this.nestedDataSource.data = data);
  }

  hasNestedChild = (_: number, nodeData: FileNode) => !nodeData.type;

  private _getChildren = (node: FileNode) => node.children;
}
```

here is my [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-crtxmm-s2bpmg?file=app/tree-nested-overview-example.html)

when i open page it should come like this

[image]

when i click ece it should come like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has the content below {{node :json}} added, you just need to get the correct data out of the node object.

```
    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle
            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
      {{node | json}}
    </button>
```

Comment: i added image pls take a look and help me i am new to this

Comment: hai can you help me on this

Answer (score -2):

```
<mat-tree>
    <mat-tree-node> Parent node name </mat-tree-node>
    <mat-tree-node> Child Node 1 </mat-tree-node>
    <mat-tree-node> Child Node 2 </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).